# Scala - How to group a list of tuples without pattern matching?

Tags: scala, group-by, tuples

Consider the following structure (in reality the structure is a bit more complex):

```
case class A(id:String,name:String) {
   override def equals(obj: Any):Boolean = {
      if (obj == null || !obj.isInstanceOf[A]) return false
      val a = obj.asInstanceOf[A]
      name == a.name
   }

   override def hashCode() = {
      31 + name.hashCode
   }
}

val a1 = A("1","a")
val a2 = A("2","a")
val a3 = A("3","b")
val list = List((a1,a2),(a1,a3),(a2,a3))
```

Now let's say I want to group all tuples with equal A's. I could implement it like this

```
list.groupBy {
  case (x,y) => (x,y)
}
```

But, I don't like to use pattern matching here, because it's not adding anything here. I want something simple, like this:

```
list.groupBy(_)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile. Not even when I do:

```
list.groupBy[(A,A)](_)
```

Any suggestions how to simplify my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> list.groupBy { case (x,y) => (x,y) }
> ```

Here you are deconstructing the tuple into its two constituent parts, just to immediately reassemble them exactly like they were before. In other words: you aren't actually doing anything useful. The input and output are identical. This is just the same as

```
list.groupBy { t => t }
```

which is of course just the identity function, which Scala helpfully provides for us:

```
list groupBy identity
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to group the elements of a list accoding to their own `equals` method, you only need to pass the identity function to groupBy:

```
list.groupBy(x=>x)
```

It's not enough to write `list.groupBy(_)` because of the scope of `_`, that is it would be desugared to `x => list.groupBy(x)`, which is of course not what you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Brian: it might very well provide an answer, because it groups the items in the list according to equals.

Comment: Kim, add more information about why your answers work or why the question does not work and your answers probably won't flagged any more as low quality. Furthermore the chance for more reputation is higher... ;)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that one. I kinda like it, because I don't care about what's inside the tuple. However, I still don't understand why list.groupBy(_) doesn't work.

Comment: This is technically commentary. If you know the answer, then post a definitive answer, otherwise, it is discussion and should be a comment. "try this" answers are not very valuable.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as the groupBy with case expression that the OP didn't like only because of the case expression usage.  So I'd call it an answer!

Comment: I would call it an answer too, I just wanted to caution that I might have misunderstood the OP because it is rather obvious.

Comment: @JeroenRosenberg: Added some more text and an explanation why `groupBy(_)` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation :)